# Unknown file in WordPress core: wp-admin/vZMw71yHdJQtdmHIRokAlLi7YAku9VfwxKPzNFBazQQ Type: File

Tags: wordpress, lets-encrypt, wordfence

Wordfence just scanned my wordpress website and foud the following file changes

```
Unknown file in WordPress core: wp-admin/vZMw71yHdJQtdmHIRokAlLi7YAku9VfwxKPzNFBazQQ
Type: File
Issue Found April 25, 2023 10:56 am
High
```

After I checked in my directory I found that these are just the keys for the SSL certificate generated from let's encrypt. How do I fix this. Should I ignore it? If I delete them my SSLs will be affected